# Apache Beam Pipeline Unit Test execution is not similar that on GCP dataflow execution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow pipeline that works fine as expected without any issues, I have started writing test cases for the transformation.

Below is one of the transformations I have where I take Table Row as input and constaruct a String as output.

I realized the code executes differently while running test cases, when I deploy in the dataflow in GCP it works as expected processing each element in the PCollection one after the other, but when I execute the same logic in the test case it is not working as expected.

Transformation:

```
public class ConstructPkIdString extend PTransform<TableRow,PcollectionTuple>{

public static final TupleTag<String> validTag = new TupleTag<>(){};

String pkId;

public ConstructPkIdString(String pkId){
this.pkId = pkId;
}
public Pcollection expand(Pcollection<tableRow> input){

StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

return input.apply("PKID String Builder", ParDe.of(new DoFn<TableRow, String>(){
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(processContext context){
           System.out.println("processing data START");
            TableRow data = context.element().clone();
            try
            {
                System.out.println("id received: " +data.get(pkId));
                System.out.println("current strbuilder: " + strBuilder);
                strBuilder.append("'"+data.get(pkId).toString()+"",");
                context.output(strBuilder.toString());

            }catch (Exception e){
                LOG.error(" Exception occurred while building string {}",e);
            }
            System.out.println("processing data END");
        }
        }).withOutputTags(validTag, TupleTagList.of(failureTag)));

}
```

Test case Code :

```
public final testPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create().enableAbandoneNodeEnforcement(false)

TestDataHelper helper = new TestdataHelper();


@Test
void testConstructPkIdString(){
    System.out.println("Test: TestConstructPkIdString is in Progress");
    String spannerPKID = "id";
    ImmutableList<TableRow> testMetaDataRecord = helper.getBQTableRecords();
    PCollection<TableRow> finalBQDataSet = pipeline.apply("testMetaDataRecord", Create.of(testMetaDataRecord));
    PCollectionTuple stringBuilderTuple = finalBQDataSet.apply("Construct String", new ConstructPkIdString(spannerPKID));
    PCollection<String> pkIdListStr = stringBuilderTuple.get(ConstructPkIdString.validTag).apply("Get Latest Element", Latest.globally())
    pkIdListStr.apply( name: "Log stringbuilder", MapElements.into (TypeDescriptor.of(String.class))
                .via(str ->{
                System.out.println("element :"+str);
                return str;
                }))
        PCollection<Long> count pkIdListStr.apply(name: "Count Success Records", Count.globally()); PCollection<Long> failureCount = failurePCollection.apply(name: "Count Failure Records", Count.globally());
        PAssert.that (count).containsInAnyOrder(1L);
        System.out.println("Test: TestConstructPkIdString is Completed");
}
```

when I execute the test case elements in the PCollection is not processing one after the other.

output :

```
    Test: TestConstructPkIdString is in Progress
    processing data START
    processing data START 

    id received :123
    id received :456

    current strbuilber: 
    current strbuilber:

    processing data END
    processing data END

    element :null
    Test: TestConstructPkIdString is Completed
```

expected output:

```
    Test: TestConstructPkIdString is in Progress

    processing data START
    id received :123
    current strbuilber: 
    processing data END

    processing data START 
    id received :456
    current strbuilber:123,
    processing data END

    element :123,456,
    Test: TestConstructPkIdString is Completed
```

Am I missing anything, not able to understand why the test case is not processing elements one after the other?

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think if you log only the output `PCollection`, you should have the expected elements. It's better to check the output and not check order in a distributed system framework.

Comment: Hi @MazlumTosun thanks for responding, element :null is the pcollection log.